# How to quit Avast temporarily?

Tags: windows-7, anti-virus, avast

I know how to shut-down Avast's shields (the options range from disable for 10 minutes to disable permanently). However, just a few minutes ago, the process `AvastSvc*32.exe` started consistently hogging 97% of my CPU power. I couldn't kill the process and neither did disabling the shields help in reducing the CPU load.

Though my laptop was connected to a wall outlet, it killed my entire battery (which is quite old). Had I been in a meeting, it would have been the end of the session. I am not sure what triggered the process to go berzerk; all I did a few moments before was to open a [Nature link](http://www.nature.com/nphys/journal/v9/n4/fig_tab/nphys2560_F1.html). Restarting the computer has fixed it temporarily.

I would like to be able to quickly kill the process if I need to in an emergency. Google provided the following two links but I am not sure that I have a solution:
 
https://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=165309.0
 
http://forums.penny-arcade.com/discussion/190086/avastsvc-exe-and-system-interrupts-sucking-down-cpu-cycles 
 
(the second link recommends turning off `Webshield.ini`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what worked for me:

1. With the <kbd>Win</kbd>+ <kbd>R</kbd> combo summon `services.msc`.
2. Right click on the service `Avast Antivirus` and click `Stop`.
3. Before it stops, `Avast` will warn you that the service is being stopped. Only if you are confident that your computer is safe (and are more worried about the `Avast` using most of your CPU availability) click the `Ok` button and the service should stop.

After a couple of minutes of stopping it, I restarted `Avast`. The load it put on my CPU after the restart was normal (i.e. less than 10%).

Answer (score 1):

Well, here's something you could do.

If on Windows Vista/7: open your start menu, type `cmd` omitting the quotes, right click on cmd (looks like a black icon with c:\ on it) select `Run As Administrator`

If on Windows 8+: press WinKey + F, type `cmd` omitting the quotes, right click on cmd (looks like a black icon with c:\ on it) select `Run As Administrator`

Once in the Command Prompt it should look something like this:

[image: Command Prompt]

NB: I use Windows 8.1 Update, yours might look slightly different.

Next, we need to type this:

`taskkill /F /IM AvastSvc.exe`

This tells Windows to launch a command, `taskkill` (Task Killer), tells `taskkill` that it needs to `/F`orce the program closed, and that the `/IM`age name is `AvastSvc.exe`

Once done, you can safely close the Command Prompt.

Comment: No it can't be done. It fails just like trying to terminate it from the task manager and yields the error whose second line is Reason:Aessisdenied.Reason: Access is denied. Just to be sure: I started it with Admin privileges just as you said.

Comment: Have you turned Avasts self protection off? OR... you could uninstall Avast.